# Open file with File() from dart:io

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

I have a flutter application with a folder certs/ inside the assets' folder like this:
certs/ with a cert.pem file inside.

I already added the file to the pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/texts/
    - assets/certs/cert.pem
```

but when I run

```
var certFile = File("cert.pem");
var certFile = File("certs/cert.pem");
var certFile = File("assets/certs/cert.pem");
var certFile = File("../../../assets/certs/cert.pem");
```

None of these options work. How to do I open the file?

Thank you

Comment: You're not opening anything with that code. You're simply declaring variables.

Comment: In which folder do you run the code?

Comment: Yes, it's not opening the file, but when I open the file after any of these declarations, it always says file not found

Answer (score 0):

You can't open Asset files like normal system files.

One way to access them is to use `rootBundle`:

```dart
Future<String> readFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}
```

Comment: But this is not a text file, is a key, how should I open this type of files?

Comment: Use [`AssetBundle.load`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/load.html) to load binary data.  Read the [`AssetBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html) documentation.